# if statements with Duration in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to classify my athletes using their time complete a task.

B22 = a calculation resulting in a Duration e.g. 00:01:46

```
= IF (B22> "00:02:00", "Novice", IF (B22>"00:01:30", "Intermediate", IF B22<= "00:01:30", "Advanced")))
```

I should get "Intermediate" as the answer, but only get #ERROR!

I suspect the issue is with the "00:00:00" duration notation.

any ideas?

thx

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? Can you post a screenshot? The formula as written has an obvious missing parenthesis after the 3rd IF, perhaps that's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the #ERROR! is a missing bracket after the final IF ( an old trick is to count up the number of left brackets and the number of right brackets - they should be equal). This would give you:

```
= IF (B22> "00:02:00", "Novice", IF (B22>"00:01:30", "Intermediate", IF (B22<= "00:01:30", "Advanced")))
```

However it doesn't give the right answer because of (as you suspected) the times. You need to put them as timevalues to compare them to a duration:

```
= IF (B22> timevalue("00:02:00"), "Novice", IF (B22>timevalue("00:01:30"), "Intermediate", IF (B22<= timevalue("00:01:30"), "Advanced")))
```

This can be simplified to:

```
= IF (B22> timevalue("00:02:00"), "Novice", IF (B22>timevalue("00:01:30"), "Intermediate",  "Advanced"))
```

because once you have eliminated the first two possibilities, "Advanced" is the only one left.

Comment: Thank you Tom.

  = IF (B22> timevalue("00:02:00"), "Novice", IF (B22>timevalue("00:01:30"), "Intermediate",  "Advanced")) is a very elegant solution.

S